# Как через v-for вывести первые 4 элемента?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]
С API мне приходит много видео, мне нужно вывести только 4

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь добавлять код текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю лучше всего сделать `computed property`:

```
computed: {
 videoPreview () {
   return video.slice(0, 4);
 }
}
```

И потом обычный `v-for`, толко по этому свойству:

```
<div v-for="(video, index) in videoPreview"> 
    <p>{{video}}</p>
</div>
```

P.S. На будущее, лучше код выкладывать текстом, а не скрином.

Comment: Ошибка: "TypeError: this.video.slice is not a function". Мне с API приходит объект с видео

Comment: Ну так я и написал примерный фукционал, как я могу написать полностью рабочий код не видя оригинальный, я рассказал принцип.